# Rails thinking sphinx includes not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I have the code like following

```
Listing.search(
      Riddle::Query.escape(params[:search]),
      :include => params[:include],
      :page => page,
      :per_page => per_page,
      :star => true,
      :with => with,
      :with_all => with_all,
      :order => params[:sort]
    )
```

params[:include] contains the value like `[:listing_images, :author, :category, :origin_loc]`

I don’t know what was wrong here.

Comment: How is it 'not' working? Do you get an error messag? Do you get inconsistent results? do you get mistaken results? Do you not understand how to decode the results? Suspect need more details to know what the problem actully is.

Comment: @barryhunter : I have used bullet gem which shows N+1 query related issus and I used rails logs for debug N+1 queries